# ncursesw on actual svga console colors are not correct

Tags: linux, ncurses

I'm using ncursesw which does output some cchar_t items, everything works fine from a terminal opened in a GUI, but when on the actual PC console, the colors are off (standard simple colors) for some of the items and those do use `setcchar(&cch, wch, WA_NORMAL, 0, NULL)` and `add_wch(&cch)`.  The color to use is set on the window using `wattrset` and `wbkgdset` prior to the `setcchar` call.   Is there a limitation using the wide chars (cchar_t) when dealing with a normal PC console?  What would that rule be?

Comment: You should probably provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

It turns out there was another routine that set the colorpair using `setcchar` and the actual attribute was used instead of the color pair number.  So while some terminals must account for that, the console didn't.  The proper value for setcchar is the color pair number (`n`) and not the result of `COLOR_PAIR(n)`